# Javascript Increment in a loop

Tags: javascript

```js
var minimumPayment = 10;
var originalBalanceOption1 = 1000;
var interestRate = 0.15;
var initMonth = 0;
while (initMonth < 12) {

  var payment = minimumPayment * originalBalanceOption1 / 100;
  var interest = ((interestRate / 12) * originalBalanceOption1 / 100);
  var principal = payment - interest;
  var newBalance = originalBalanceOption1 - principal;
  document.write(initMonth.toFixed(2) + '----' + payment.toFixed(2) + '----' + principal.toFixed(2) + '----' + newBalance.toFixed(2));
  document.write('<br>');
  initMonth++;
}
```

I am trying to work with this finance calculator, I am building. I am new to javascript. I am trying to loop, but i am getting the first value of the row only.

Comment: Seems to work with edits. I added top three vars.

Comment: should I use -> console.log

Comment: For testing it doesn't matter. Once you are ready to use the results you'll want to choose a different method of writing to the page.

Comment: I really like, but i am getting the same values like you. How do I do a loop with logically.

Answer (score 0):

The issue with your code is that you don't carry the new balance into the next iteration of your loop. Instead you start your calculations in *each* iteration based on the *initial* balance.

With minimal changes to your code, you can make it work like this:

```js
var minimumPayment = 10;
var originalBalanceOption1 = 1000;
var interestRate = 0.15;
var initMonth = 0;

var newBalance = originalBalanceOption1; // Work with newBalance, not with original
while (initMonth < 12) {
  var payment = minimumPayment * newBalance / 100;
  var interest = ((interestRate / 12) * newBalance / 100);
  var principal = payment - interest;
  newBalance = newBalance - principal;
  document.write(initMonth.toFixed(2) + '----' + payment.toFixed(2) + '----' + principal.toFixed(2) + '----' + newBalance.toFixed(2));
  document.write('<br>');
  initMonth++;
}
```

But I would advise you to:

- create a function for it, which takes parameters.
- use a `for` loop instead of a `while` loop
- don't (ever) use `document.write`. If the reason for it is to just see the progress of the code, use `console.log` instead. If it is to display the information in a web page, then use other DOM methods.
- It will be useful to store the 12 payments in an array, and let the function return that array. You can then afterwards decide what to do with the array: print it with `console.log` or use it for a representation on a web page.

Here is such an implementation:

```js
function getPayments(minimumPaymentPct, originalBalance, interestRate) {
    const payments = [];
    for (let month = 0, balance = originalBalance; month < 12; month++) {
        const payment = minimumPaymentPct * balance;
        const interest = ((interestRate / 12) * balance / 100);
        const principal = payment - interest;
        balance -= principal;
        payments.push({
            payment: +payment.toFixed(2), 
            principal: +principal.toFixed(2), 
            balance: +balance.toFixed(2)
        });
    }
    return payments;
}

const payments = getPayments(0.10, 1000, 0.15);
console.log(payments);
```